# Which clustering algorithm is most suitable for grouping by set overlap?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

I'm trying to cluster sets by their similarity in terms of included elements. The group of possible elements is of size ~1 million. It is my understanding that in order to run k-means or a similar algorithm I'd have to create a dataframe that has a correspondingly large number of columns. This doesn't seem feasible.

Is there a clustering algorithm better suited for this problem? Will I be able to solve this problem as I've formulated it?

Comment: How many sets do you have?

Comment: If size is an issue consider using Klara algorithm.

Comment: @user20160 roughly 500,000 sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement k-means with *sparse* data points. You just may need to do this yourself, rather than relying on someone else's code to be memory efficient enough for you.

However, k-means is likely not a good idea for other reasons: it requires continuous variables for it's least-squares and *mean* based approach to make sense.

On *sets*, the obvious alternative is to use an actual **frequent itemset mining** approach to identify common subsets.